# Saving and retrieving the JSON response in android SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, json, sharedpreferences

I am a newbie and i'm developing the android app that has the login activity and when user is successful logged in  it returns the following JSON response

```
[{
    "id" : 3,
    "username" : "test"
}]
```

I want to store the "**id**" in `SharedPreferences` and use it across the whole application.

Here are my login activity code:

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(s);
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject post = jArray.optJSONObject(i);
    user_id = post.getString("id");
    SharedPreferences sp=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("usersinfos", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putString("userid", user_id );
    editor.commit();
}
```

Here my **profile activity**

```
SharedPreferences sp = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("usersinfos",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String user_id= sp.getString("userid", "");
Toast.makeText(getActivity(),user_id , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The result the Toast gives is empty.

Comment: Did you verify that you actually save what you think you save? Perhaps you should add a toast for the saving part as well to make sure.

Comment: Try first to manually save something in SharedPreferences with out getting it from JSONObject. Then, see if you see it in the Toast. That way you'll see if the problem is parsing the JSON string or if the problem is SharedPreferences.

Comment: i tried this it works great

Comment: Can you show the value of `s` in this line? `JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(s);`

Comment: yes the i can get the value of s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The id is not a string, it should be "3" to be a string.
Try saving an integer with `putInt` and `getInt`

Comment: Did you change this line? `user_id = post.getString("id");`. Use the debugger and see if it returns a value

Comment: Use the debugger and tell us what do you get

Comment: Sorry nothing showing up regarding sharedpreferences in debugger

Comment: Debug this line `user_id = post.getInt("id");` and see if the correct value is set

Comment: Sorry i failed to get debug of single line